# Finding an element within an element using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, webdriver

I am scraping a website that has a list of football games generated using JavaScript. I have written the following line that creates a list of all the game elements on the page:

```
list = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@data-sportid="1"]')
```

If I then write

```
for game in list:
    print game.text
```

it prints all the text fields contained in each of the games (home team name, away team name, etc.)

However, the loop

```
for game in list:
    print game.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="home-team"]').text
```

prints the very first home team's name in the page for each iteration of the loop.

It appears that `game.find_element_by_xpath` is searching the entire page, and not just this `game` element, and so it keeps returning the first home team name on the page.

How can I search for a child element within each item of the list?

**EDIT**

[Here is the exact page I am working on](https://www.betfair.com/exchange/football/coupon?id=2)

Comment: can u give us the site?\

Comment: @nooby added it to the question

Answer (score 25, accepted):

@Justin Bartz Thank you.

You were using XPath `//*[@class="home-team"]` but no matter what parent element you are using the `//` tells XPath to search the whole document not just the children of the parent element.
Using the XPath `.//*[@class="home-team"]` with the period in front of the forward slashes (IE .//) it tells it to search under the current element only.

Hope this expanded explanation helps the understanding.

```
   driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("https://www.betfair.com/exchange/football/coupon?id=2")
    list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@data-sportid="1"]')
    for game in list:
        print(game.find_element_by_css_selector('span.home-team').text)

or

    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("https://www.betfair.com/exchange/football/coupon?id=2")
    list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@data-sportid="1"]')
    for game in list:
        print(game.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@class="home-team"]').text)
```

Comment: The explanation from Justin's answer is key to learning what happened and to stop making the same mistake again. It should be incorporated into this answer.

Comment: I've been searching for the whole internet for how to solve this. And the answer is a single "." at the start of the xpath. Thank you Barney!

Answer (score 16):

This is to add an explanation to Barneys answer.

You were using xpath  `//*[@class="home-team"]` but no matter what parent element you are using the `//` tells xpath to search the whole document not just the children of the parent element.
Using the xpath `.//*[@class="home-team"]`  with the period in front of the forward slashes (IE `.//`) it tells it to search under the current element only.

Hope this expanded explanation helps the understanding.