# Unable to write extracted text as individual rows in csv

Tags: python, csv, selenium, web-scraping

This may be considered as second part of question [Finding an element within an element using Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43441269/finding-an-element-within-an-element-using-selenium-webdriver/43443221#43443221).

What Im doing here is, after extracting each text from the table, writing it into csv file

Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import csv

chromeDriver = "/home/manoj/workspace2/RedTools/test/chromedriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromeDriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromeDriver)
driver.get("https://www.betfair.com/exchange/football/coupon?id=2")
list2 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@data-sportid="1"]')

couponlist = []
finallist = []
for game in list2[1:]:
    coup = game.find_element_by_css_selector('span.home-team').text
    print(coup)
    couponlist.append(coup)
print(couponlist)
print('its done')


outfile = open("./footballcoupons.csv", "wb")
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerow(["Games"])
writer.writerows(couponlist)
```

Results of 3 print statements:

```
Santos Laguna
CSMS Iasi
AGF
Besiktas
Malmo FF
Sirius
FCSB
Eibar
Newcastle
Pescara

[u'Santos Laguna', u'CSMS Iasi', u'AGF', u'Besiktas', u'Malmo FF', u'Sirius', u'FCSB', u'Eibar', u'Newcastle', u'Pescara']

its done
```

Now, You can notice the code where i write these values into csv. But I end up writing it weirdly into csv. please see the snapshot. Can someone help me to fix this please?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#writer-objects), `writerows` takes as parameter a list of rows, and

> A row must be an iterable of strings or numbers for Writer objects

You are passing a list of strings, so `writerows` iterates over your strings, making a row out of each character.

You could use a loop:

```
for team in couponlist:
    writer.writerow([team])
```

or turn your list into a list of lists, then use `writerows` :

```
couponlist = [[team] for team in couponlist]
writer.writerows(couponlist)
```

But anyway, there's no need to use `csv` if you only have one column...

Comment: perfect.. thank you @thierry-lathuille. It worked.. Specially, liked the last line. Cheers!