# Can't find sub element with WebDriver Xpath

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I'm trying to get prices for games in steam store.
Here' a webpage screen [image: red values need to be captured]

Here's my code

```
    @Test

    public void testDriver() {
    WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
    FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.get("https://store.steampowered.com/search/?term=Dying+Light+-+Viking%3A+Raiders+of+Harran+Bundle&ndl=1");

    List<WebElement> gameContainers = driver.findElements(By.xpath("(//div[@id='search_resultsRows']//a)"));

    System.out.println(gameContainers.get(0).findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='col search_price  responsive_secondrow']")).getText());
    System.out.println(gameContainers.get(1).findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='col search_price  responsive_secondrow']")).getText());
}
```

The output should be `8,20 TL and 47,13 TL,` but instead I have double `8,20 TL and 8,20 TL`
no matter that I call for different elements from my `List<WebElement> gameContainers`

How it can be and where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

[Here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43441269/finding-an-element-within-an-element-using-selenium-webdriver)

Sorry for inconvenience

I forgot to use `.//` instead of `//` while using xpath